# Small xarray object killing Dask worker when attempting computations

Tags: python-xarray

I am working with an hourly temperature dataset and trying to pare it down to daily max/min/average values for a given country in a given year. My code is as follows:

```
def daily_temps_year(country, year, utc_offset):
    '''
    Takes in a country and a year and creates daily totals for that country (assuming the country spans a single time zone).
    '''
    full_year = xr.open_mfdataset(FILEPATH + year + '_*.nc')
    full_year = full_year.rename({'longitude': 'lon',
                             'latitude': 'lat'})
    full_year = full_year.assign_coords({"lon": (((full_year.lon + 180) % 360) - 180)})
    mask_3d = regionmask.defined_regions.natural_earth.countries_110.mask_3D(full_year)
    country = mask_3d.isel(region=(mask_3d.names == country))
    country = country.drop(['region', 'names', 'abbrevs'])
    country = country.squeeze(dim='region', drop=True)
    country_temp_full = full_year.where(country, drop=True)
    country_temp_full = country_temp_full.assign_coords({'time': country_temp_full.time+pd.Timedelta(utc_offset, unit='h')})
    daily_avg = country_temp_full.resample(time='1D').mean()
    daily_max = country_temp_full.resample(time='1D').max()
    daily_min = country_temp_full.resample(time='1D').min()
    daily_avg = daily_avg.rename({'t2m': 'mean_temp'})
    daily_max = daily_max.rename({'t2m': 'max_temp'})
    daily_min = daily_min.rename({'t2m': 'min_temp'})
    merged_temp_full = xr.merge([daily_avg, daily_max, daily_min])
    return merged_temp_full
```

I ran the code for Mali in 2017, which returns an array of size 5.69 MB. When I try to display the maximum values, call .compute() on the array, or save the file as a netCDF, the dask worker gets killed. The full 2017 dataset being opened by xr.open_mfdataset is about 40 GB, and I am running the code on a distributed computing cluster. When I print out the client object, it confirms there are 40 workers and 160 GB of memory, so I'm not sure why it's getting overloaded. Any advice would be wonderful!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It is quite difficult to help you without the access to the data or the full code (you have some global variables being called within this function, e.g. regionmask). I suggest you either create an xarray object with the same structure using dummy data or trying to give more information about the problem you're facing.

Comment: The idea is to make is as clean as possible for other users replicate the error you are having. It can also help you to check what is happening. You can try to comment line by line of the function to see if the code works without some of it.

Comment: Totally agree with @iury simones-sousa on the benefit of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. But just going off a hunch - is the result of your function indexed by lat, lon? If so, open_mfdataset will try to align these indices and you'll get nearly the whole world represented in your grid (including the ocean) even if it's not in the individual country arrays. Most of it will be NaN, but it will still take up a ton of memory. If that's the issue, one giant DataArray probably isn't your best option.